# Disable personalize your web experience is Edge IE mode

Tags: microsoft-edge

How can we disable the personalize your web experience prompt while launching Edge IE Mode using selenium ?

Not able to find any capabilities for this setting in edge ie mode. Adding ie command line switches to in private mode is not working

Comment: Could you please tell us which language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code logic to handle the notification

EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();                        
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");      
Map<String, Object> prefs = new LinkedHashMap<>();          
prefs.put("user_experience_metrics.personalization_data_consent_enabled", Boolean.valueOf(true));           
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);          
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```